# UISwitch looks strange on IOS5 simulator and device

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiswitch

When i add UISwitch in IB it looks as it should. But when i run my app in 5.0 simulator or on 5.0 device, i get this:
[image]

If i run it on ios4 simulator everything looks ok. This a large project that has three20 included and was transformed to ARC with XCode.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get on iOS 5 is the [new Switch Control](http://benjaminmayo.posterous.com/new-switch-control-in-ios5).

Comment: New switch control shouldn't have that white vertical line, should it?

Comment: @Kreiri - according to the link sergio provided, the text of the switch is dependent on the locale of the build (not sure how to correctly say that), from that link: "in non-English builds, where the control isn't labelled with "On" or "Off", but rather "O" or "I", like a power switch."

Comment: @PeterM it's not the locale of the *build*, but rather the locale of the device on which the code is running.  So if you take that same code and run it on an english iPhone, you'll see "On" and "Off".

Comment: Yeah, Dave DeLong is right. It's the device's locale that makes the difference. I'll update the post.